# Java: Which has more performance - for pushing a stream to a string?

Tags: java, string, performance, file, inputstream

I wrote a utility method to write some **small** data from a stream to a `String`.

Which implementation has more performance?

1. Write all data to a byte array and then **convert all of them to `String` at once**.

OR

2. **Convert each buffered part to `String` and concatenate them**.

---

Implementation 1:

```
private String fileToString() throw ... {
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[bufLen];
    int n;
    
    final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((n = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, n);
    
    return new String(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
}
```

Implementation 2:

```
private String fileToString() throw ... {
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[bufLen];
    int n;
    
    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(aProperValue);
    while ((n = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
        stringBuilder.append(new String(buffer, 0, n, "UTF-8"));
    
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

**The second implementation is not correct! I was wrong! See my answer below.**

Comment: @ThomasS. Perhaps will do it. But it would be good to make it **accessible for all on the web**.

Comment: The second one is incorrect: it might read half a character (since UTF8 encodes some characters to several bytes) and try to transform this half sequence to a character. Why don't you use a Reader to read characters? That's what they're for.

Comment: Don't forget to read about [how to write a correct micro-benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) before you try it.

Comment: https://javapapers.com/java/java-string-vs-stringbuilder-vs-stringbuffer-concatenation-performance-micro-benchmark/

Comment: I think you'll likely find that for small strings, both approaches perform about the same. This is probably a micro-optimization.

Comment: What are you reading *from*?  The performance of your IO device(s) will likely dominate the performance of your entire application.

Comment: @JBNizet. No. From the documentation of `String (byte[], int, int, String)`: "The length of the new String is a function of the charset, and hence may not be equal to the length of the subarray". Also I tested it: `new String("αβγδε".getBytes(), 0, "αβγδε".getBytes().length, "UTF-8")` is equal to `"αβγδε"`.

Comment: @Mir-Ismaili `fileInputStream.read(buffer)` reads *bytes*, not *UTF-8 characters*.  `fileInputStream.read(buffer)` can indeed split a UTF-8 character into multiple bytes.

Comment: @Mir-Ismaili you didn't get me. Suppose your String has two chars. Suppose encoding the first char to UTF8 gives the bytes [192, 128], and the encoding of the second gives [193, 129]. Now suppose that, when reading these bytes, you first get [192, 128, 193]. You'll transform these three bytes to a String, thus trying to decode the byte 193 as a character, which is invalid.

Comment: @JBNizet. OK. Very thank you. The issue has been cleared! There is only one way. I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The second implementation is wrong. It doesn't work at boundaries! Thank [@JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) and [@Andrew Henle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4756299/andrew-henle). See their comments under my question.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use some library. I've tried to solve same issue by myself, but performance was really slow. Consider using `CharStreams.toString` from `Guava` library, you'll see increased performance with naked eye.

Comment: Why add a library hog if you can solve a tiny problem with some thinking?